# What restrictions are there on Teleport/Leap/movement abilities?

Tags: diablo-iii

The Wizard's Teleport and the Barbarian's Leap both allow them to move to a new location. In using Teleport, I've noticed there are some times when I can teleport to a location my mouse is on, and there are some times I cannot. I suspect Leap is similar.

How can I tell what I can teleport to - that is, how do I know if my teleport will be successful or if I will teleport to my current location? How are movement abilities restricted?

Comment: There is also the Monk's first skill rune that teleports them to their target. This is based on line of sight and solid path as well.

Comment: Incidentally, I recently learned how to do this with leap and it is *freaking awesome*.  I can save massive amounts of walking by leaping up and down across elevation changes in various areas.  I leap for the hell of it quite a lot now, just to cover ground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From experience with Leap alone, it appears that there are two restrictions on movement abilities.

1) You cannot leap across/over areas that are shown on the map as impassible. This is terrain you would not normally be able to walk across like the trees in the areas outside Tristram or gaps in the various dungeons. You can leap from different levels in dungeons provided those areas are adjacent to one another and not separated by a gap through which you can see the "background". Your character model might look like it jumps or teleports but the game checks the terrain below you to make sure you would normally be able to stand on it. This means that if the "invisible wall" separating where you are from where you want to go is thin enough the game places you on one side or the other at any given time.

2) You need line of sight but you don't appear to actually need vision. This applies when jumping up from a lower area to a higher one. If you are able to see where you start your movement from where you end it, it seems to allow you to complete your movement as intended. This means that your destination can actually be in the "fog of war" but you can't jump to the other side of a solid wall (since you can't see where you started from where you land).

Comment: Regarding point 1, I recall being able to leap down levels over railings; it's finicky, but sometimes works (kinda like firing spells over railings to the lower level).  I think that's what you're getting at, the first sentence is a bit confusing.

Comment: Can jump across non-walkable (your comment) or can't ("checks terrain below to make sure...stand on it")?  *I think* those cracks near the cemetery at the north of some act 1 zone are jumpable.  *However*, the first rune/first Monk spirit generator didn't teleport me across those cracks.  In short, I'm thinking it all just boils down to wherever you can fire a spell.

Answer (score 0):

You can only teleport to an area within your characters line of sight. So you cannot teleport to the other side of a wall.
You must also be able to stand at the location you are teleporting to.

As for how to know.. You'll probably learn after playing for a while

Comment: There have been chasms I couldn't teleport across, higher or lower levels that are relatively close (horizontally) that I couldn't teleport across, and walls that I *have* teleported across...